# Error while running the docker image | JNI error

Tags: java, docker, gradle, apache-kafka

I am getting an error while running a docker image. I have created a core java application using gradle.

using `docker build` command to create the docker image and while running the docker image I am getting the following error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

I can see that the error is due to missing kafka consumer library, but I am not able to understand what I have missed in the docker file which is causing this issue.

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD build/libs/*.jar parallel.jar

RUN bash -c 'touch /parallel.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "parallel.jar"]
```

Before I ran the `docker build` command, I made sure to run the `gradle clean build` command.

Here are the dependencies I have used in `build.gradle`

```
    implementation "io.confluent.parallelconsumer:parallel-consumer-core:0.5.2.4"
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1"
    implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:3.3.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13"
    implementation "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0"
    implementation "me.tongfei:progressbar:0.9.3"
    implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
    implementation("log4j:log4j:1.2.17")
```

Comment: Can you try running without Docker? Do you have the same issue?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `RUN bash -c 'touch /parallel.jar'`. What are you aiming for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't include dependencies, by default. You'd get the same error when running `java jar` outside of the container.

You need to use shadow plugin to get dependencies packaged in your JAR.

Alternatively, don't write a Dockerfile manually... Use `jib-gradle-plugin`. Plus, it'll create a more optimized Docker image, which doesn't create an Uber JAR like the shadow plugin would.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I created a jar file using `shadowJar`. I am able to run the jar file in my system but when I try to run it in the container getting an error `Error: Unable to access jarfile parallel.jar io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication`
docker last line is `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "parallel.jar io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication"]`

Comment: I think you meant `"parallel.jar", "..."]` (separate arguments)? But also, `java -jar` command doesn't accept a classname , only a JAR file. Anything afterwards is passed as a plain string into `String[] args` of the JAR's own `MainClass`... Plus, you seem to have ignored my recommendation to use Jib and not write a Dockerfile at all

Comment: I will be taking a look at the Jib as well. It's just that I was already using the ShadowJar to create the jar file so though of using it to create the docker image. In my local once the jar is created I run the jar by passing the class like this `java -cp build/libs/paralelConsumer.jar io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication` where `io.confluent.developer.ParallelConsumerApplication` is the class which contains the main function if I don't mention the main class I get the error `no main manifest attribute`. So while creating the jar where can I mention about the main class

Comment: The main class should be an option in the shadowJar config in your grade file. `java -cp` takes a class name, yes. `java -jar` does not